# Using aggregate function in azure data factory to sum values

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a csv file in my ADLS with about 40 columns, from there, I want to use azure data factory to do what this python code does:

```
fastfoodchain_grouped = df.groupby(['Fast Food Chain','State','Month'])
sum_each = fastfoodchain_grouped['Sales'].agg(np.sum)
```

Sample Data:

```
Fast Food Chain,State,Month,Sales
Mc Donalds,New York,February,1000.05
KFC,Boston,January,200.10
KFC,Texas,March,-1050
Mc Donalds,Boston,March,20000
Burger King,New York,February,1500.20
Burger King,New York,March,2500
Burger King,Texas,January ,4000
Wendy's ,Boston,January,3000
Mc Donalds,New York,February,-50
Mc Donalds,Texas,January,1000
```

Image of data flow:
[image: Dataflow]
[image]
I tried to use the aggregate function in data flow, but when I try to sum my Sales column by doing sum(Sales) I am getting a type mismatch error.

Appreciate some help on this. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide sample data and image of data flow?

Comment: @PratikLad Hi I've edited to include them :)

Comment: Can you show aggregates section of the transformation?

Comment: @PratikLad Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The above error, arise when you are using functions on wrong data type columns. `sum()` can only be used in numeric columns.

You need to **import the schema in the mapping tab of the source** to detect the correct data types from the source csv files.

[image]

Make sure its data type is a numeric and not a string type.

You can see I am getting expected results with same data when the data type is numeric.

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks rakesh, tried out your solution and it worked